# Is it possible to run an Insert and Get by dapper simultaneously?

Tags: dapper

Using ASP.NET Core3.1 and  Dapper, I want to insert a record to my database and get the whole table as result ! Currently I have two queries in my `repository` as below:
First: to insert a record to my data base:

```
   //some codes here
  string sql = "UPDATE likes AS L SET L.isLike = @isLikeSQL WHERE L.ItemId = @ItemIdSQL  AND L.Ip = @IpSQL ";
  await dbConnection.ExecuteAsync(sql, new { ItemIdSQL = ItemId, senderpSQL = Ip, isLikeSQL = isLike });
```

Second: To get the whole table after inserting the top record:

```
//some codes here
string sql = " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes AS I WHERE I.ItemId = @itemIdSQL  AND I.isLike=1; " +
            " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM map118.likes AS I WHERE I.ItemId = @itemIdSQL  AND I.isLike=0; ";
using (var data = await dbConnection.QueryMultipleAsync(sql, new { itemIdSQL = ItemId }))
    {
      numberOfLikes = data.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault();
      numberOfDislikes = data.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I need to know if I can have all above in one query by dapper !! In fact we have `QueryMultipleAsync` in dapper that can manage more than one query ( AS I have done myself ) but I do not know if we can merge an `ExecuteAsync` and `QueryAsync` and have them all in one query for better performance. I need something like this :

```
string sql =
 "UPDATE likes AS L SET L.isLike = @isLikeSQL WHERE L.ItemId = @ItemIdSQL  AND  L.Ip = @IpSQL " +
 " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes AS I WHERE I.ItemId = @itemIdSQL  AND  L.isLike=1; "

using (var data = await dbConnection.QueryOrExecute???(sql, new { itemIdSQL = ItemId }))
    {
      numberOfLikes = data.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault();
      numberOfDislikes = data.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE` doesn't return a grid (unless you are using the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql). You can do as many operations as you *like* in a SQL operation - all that Dapper cares about is the result grids, so yes, you can perform an `update` *and* (separately) a `select`. The only significance of `Execute` over `Query` is that `Execute` expects *zero* grids. If you're returning a single grid, then `Query`; if you're returning multiple grids: `QueryMultiple`. Dapper has no interest in what happens inside the query - it is entirely opaque - *all it sees is result grids*.

I **highly** recommend using the formal operation separator (`;`), though. For example:

```cs
const string sql = @"
UPDATE likes AS L
SET L.isLike = @isLike
WHERE L.ItemId = @ItemId AND L.Ip = @Ip;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes AS I WHERE I.ItemId = @ItemId AND L.isLike=1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes AS I WHERE I.ItemId = @ItemId AND L.isLike=0;
"
using (var data = await dbConnection.QueryMultipleAsync(sql,
    new { ItemId, isLike, Ip }))
{
    numberOfLikes = data.ReadSingle<int>();
    numberOfDislikes = data.ReadSingle<int>();
}
```

although to be honest I might be tempted to do, instead, a single final `select`, using Dapper's positional treatment of value-tuples:

```cs
const string sql = @"
UPDATE likes AS L
SET L.isLike = @isLike
WHERE L.ItemId = @ItemId AND L.Ip = @Ip;

SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes AS I WHERE I.ItemId = @ItemId AND L.isLike=1),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes AS I WHERE I.ItemId = @ItemId AND L.isLike=0);
"
(var numberOfLikes, var numberOfDislikes) =
    await dbConnection.QuerySingleAsync<(int,int)>(sql,
    new { ItemId, isLike, Ip });
```

or something involving `group by L.isLike`

Comment: Simple, short, instructive and complete answer :)

Comment: Dear master, where is `using()` statement in your `Dapper's positional treatment of value-tuples` ?? . How you add `using()` to `(var numberOfLikes, var numberOfDislikes) =
    await dbConnection.QuerySingleAsync<(int,int)>(sql,
    new { ItemId, isLike, Ip });` I get error  
CS1674 '(int int1, int int2)': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'.

Comment: @ehsan_kabiri_33 you don't; you only need `using` with`QueryMultiple`, because of the ambiguous lifetime. With things like `Query` or `QuerySingle`, the library deals with lifetime concerns internally, so you don't have to. What do you imagine `using` would *add* in the case of `QuerySingle`?